# Transfer data from iPad app to PC(Ubuntu) without internet

Tags: ios

I want to transfer data from iPad app to Ubuntu. For example: a `UITextField` string to Ubuntu/PC.

Is it possible to use a cable? If so Ubuntu can read the USB port?

Comment: Do iPad and PC have wifi connections ( no need for Internet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by using `GCDAsyncSocket` and here is an example
[PiTalk](https://github.com/davidahouse/PiTalk)